# create json object for vector<bool> using nlohman json

Tags: json, c++11, nlohmann-json

I want to convert a `vector<bool> vec = {true, false,true}` to json object using ***nlohman json lib*** to send through restapi.

I expect the converted json object in the form

```
{
  "data" : [true, false, true]
}
```

Comment: Example: https://godbolt.org/z/YYhx6YvcW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this in nlohmann/json, all that needs doing is creating an empty nlohmann JSON object and assigning the boolean vector to a field, "data".

e.g.

```
std::vector<bool> vec = {true, false, true};

nlohmann::json j;
j["data"] = vec;
```

yields the json object

```
{
    "data":[true,false,true]
}
```